# How to append json data to array in order to populate the TableViewCell?

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I parsed a local `.json` file from my local directory, but i am having issues with appending or assigning the parsed `json` into my array and cannot display the data in tableView.

here is what i did and it did not work:

```
  func readFile(forName name: String) {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .alwaysMapped)
                let jsonObj = try JSON(data: data)
                print("jsonData:\(jsonObj)")
                self.refreshData(data: data)
            } catch let error {
                print("parse error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        } else {
            print("Invalid filename/path.")
        }
        
    }
```

self.refreshData():

```
func refreshData(data: [Issue: Any] ) {
        self.data = data
        self.symptomsTableView.reloadData() 
}
```

is there any possible way to accomplish this..?

Comment: It would be heplful, if you also share the content of your json file and your UITableViewDataSource methods.

Comment: Have you tried with dummy data directly in the code (not the file) to verify that you have the table view properly set up? I mean adding a button that will call refreshData with some dummy data to see if the table view is updated. My bet is that you might have missed the part where you set the table view's data source and delegate.

Comment: This code won't pass compilation. `init(contentsOf:options:)` of `Data` returns `Data` and you are trying to pass that to `refreshData(data:)` function that accepts `[Issue: Any]` as parameter.